# Image size bigger issue

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload, supee-10266

I applied SUPEE-10266 patch earlier but now I found changes in `Mage_Core_Model_File_Validator_Image` file, Due to these changes Image size is getting bigger than actual size after upload. Can anyone please suggest the solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, In `app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\File\Validator\Image.php` [imagecreatetruecolor](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php) function was creating a true color image.

Comment: How did you fix this?